# Generating a pdf of textual data on iPhone/iPod touch, how to begin?

Tags: database, ios, pdf-generation

Is it possible to generate a pdf with ios sdk?
I have some textual notes (in a sqlite db) and I would generate a pdf with all of them or with only one.
How to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, [The Quartz 2D Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) is a good place to start